# Update table via a relation table

Tags: sql, db2

I have a table that record season score like **score_table** below.
It records one subject three-season score S1, S2, and S3.

And sometimes one can give up some seasons score and makeup later by getting another subject same season score, so we have **transfe_record** table to save it.

So the question is how can I write back the score using **transfe_record** using SQL(DB2) code

Thanks!

**score_table**

```
|      key     |     subject   |     S1    |     S2    |     S3    |
+--------------+---------------+-----------+-----------+-----------|
|       1      |       A01     |     80    |    80     |     100   |
|       1      |       A02     |     78    |    98     |     null  |
|       1      |       A03     |     null  |    80     |     null  |
|       1      |       B01     |     null  |    null   |     null  |
|       1      |       B02     |     null  |    null   |     60    |
|       1      |       B03     |     66    |    null   |     null  |
```

**transfe_record**

```
|       key     |    org_sbj    |    trans_sbj   |
+---------------+---------------+----------------+
|        1      |      A02      |      B02       |
|        1      |      A03      |      B03       |
```

After SQL the **score_table** should be

```
|      key     |     subject   |     S1    |     S2    |     S3    |
+--------------+---------------+-----------+-----------+-----------|
|       1      |       A01     |     80    |    80     |     100   |
|       1      |       A02     |     78    |    98     |     60    |
|       1      |       A03     |     66    |    80     |     null  |
|       1      |       B01     |     null  |    null   |     null  |
|       1      |       B02     |     null  |    null   |     60    |
|       1      |       B03     |     66    |    null   |     null  |
```

Comment: Why `(select S1 from score_table where key=1 and subject='A03') = 60` for `After SQL`? Shouldn't it be `66`?

Comment: Also, does it have to be a single query or it can be 3? (one for each season)

Comment: @MarkBarinstein My bad. Yes, your right.

Comment: @kkuduk Yes, it can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
merge into score_table a using
(
select t.key, t.org_sbj, b.S1, b.S2, b.S3
from transfe_record t
join score_table b on b.key=t.key and b.subject=t.trans_sbj
) m on m.key=a.key and m.org_sbj=a.subject  
and (a.S1 is null or a.S2 is null or a.S3 is null)
when matched then update set 
  S1=coalesce(a.S1, m.S1)
, S2=coalesce(a.S2, m.S2)
, S3=coalesce(a.S3, m.S3);
```

---

Select statement to insert into a new table:

```
select 
  a.key, a.subject
, coalesce(a.S1, b.S1) as S1
, coalesce(a.S2, b.S2) as S2
, coalesce(a.S3, b.S3) as S3
from score_table a
left join transfe_record t on t.key=a.key and t.org_sbj=a.subject
left join score_table b on b.key=t.key and b.subject=t.trans_sbj;
```

Comment: Do you want to insert duplicate records into your `score_table`? If no, then inform us where the source data is, and what table you want to insert data into. Or do you want just to get a `select` statement returning the latest result set you mentioned in the question?

Comment: I was thinking to insert into a new table. But anyway my original problem is solved.

Comment: @Billy `select` for `insert` has been added.